# MessagingSleuthOperators fails during test (beanFactory is null)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a spring boot app that uses sleuth for message tracing, in my code I use the method

```
MessagingSleuthOperators.withSpanInScope(beanFactory, message, unused -> {
            doSomething(...);
        });
```

During testing I want to call my surrounding logic to test it's functionality. Unfortunately the sleuthOperators call crashes with a NullPointerException since the beanFactory is null (which makes sense since I do not load the context in my unit test).

Is there a way to mock this beanFactory to still be able to call the sleuth operators? Is there a workaround without using the operators that can be more easily mocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static instance of `BeanFactory` which is `StaticListableBeanFactory`. You'd have to fill it out with missing beans though. `StaticListableBeanFactory` has the `addBean` method where you can add the beans (those could be mocks I guess).

Example https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/602749a8d148c281e9f519a1ef362744eeff1f44/spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/kafka/TracingKafkaProducerTest.java#L81-L86

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately I do not find a way to mock the actual span being returned by sleuth.